# Facebook Authentication as App

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

To begin, I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK within a JSP.

I'm developing a custom Facepile component.  The idea is that I want to pull back a list of people attending a public Facebook event (public in that the creator of the event has set it to be "public").  I then want to be able to toggle between showing "everyone" that is going to the event and showing "friends" (as in Facebook friends) who are going to the event.  I understand that the latter requires the "friends_events" permission as part of my access token.

Currently, I am able to do all of this just fine.  I'm comfortable working within Graph and with using FQL.  What I'm struggling with is that, in the case I'm just going to show "everyone" attending the event, I don't want to require the user to log into Facebook.  In looking through the documentation, I see that to get a list of all attendees for a public event, I will still need an access token.  However, I can't seem to find any good documentation about how to use this access token to forgo user authentication with Facebook.

So, in short, what I'm looking for is:

1) Is there any way I can get the list of attendees to a public Facebook event without having to get the user to log in?

2) If so, could you provide an example of how to do this?  Right now I'm able to get an access token using my app for authentication but, now that I've got the token, I'm unsure how to actually use it (i.e. it doesn't look like either FB.init or FB.api takes an access token as a parameter).

Thanks much and please let me know if I can clarify anything further!